# Is it mandatory to have rich snippets for AMP pages?

Tags: google-search-console, rich-snippets, structured-data, amp

I recently created AMP pages (Google's Accelerated Mobile Pages) as per the requirements mentioned in [AMP Project Documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec.html). I didn't add any rich snippets as it was non-mandatory (although recommended) as per the documentation (refer to metadata section).

However, after going live, I have received the following errors in the Google Search Console:

> **Add required structured data to your AMP pages**
>
> Google systems have detected that some of your AMP pages are missing structured data that is required for the page to appear in Google Search results with AMP-related features. The following report provides examples of pages with this (and other) errors:

Is it mandatory to have structured data (rich snippets) in the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The [*AMP HTML Specification*](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec.html) and AMP-related features offered by Google Search are separate things (in the same way as Schema.org and Google Rich Snippets are separate things). If you want to have a conforming AMP page, it only matters what the linked specification says. As you noted, [AMP does not require structured data](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec.html#metadata).

The notice quoted from Google Search Console says that structured data is required for getting AMP-related features in Google Search, not for conforming to the AMP HTML spec. If you don’t provide certain structured data, your page doesn’t get the feature in Google Search; but nothing else happens.

One example are the [Top Stories with AMP](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/carousels/top-stories). If you, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35711711/1591669), don’t provide Schema.org’s `image` property in your AMP HTML page, your page is not eligible for getting displayed in the Top Stories carousel.